# Problema na editText dentro de um ListView

Tags: android, listview, edittext

[image: Essa é a imagem da editext dentro da listview]Olá,
Criei uma lista de perguntas dentro de uma ListView, criei todas perguntas programando, não estou fazendo nenhum componente no layout.xml, apenas tem um frameLayout, mas no momento que eu clico na edittext ela não deixa eu digitar, eu clico e o teclado do celular aparece e some rapidamente, alguém sabe o que pode ser? E como solucionar ?

Segue o código da criação da editext:

```
public LinearLayout createEditText(String question, int line, EditText editText){

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lpView = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams
            lpViewEdit = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tv.setText(question);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lpView);
    linearLayout.addView(tv);

    editText= new EditText(context);
    editText.setEnabled(true);
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    editText.setFocusable(true);
    editText.setMaxLines(10);
    editText.setEms(2);
    editText.setLayoutParams(lpViewEdit);
    linearLayout.addView(editText);

    return linearLayout;
}
```

Segue o código onde estou chamando esse metodo de criação:

```
editText = new EditText(context);
        frameLayout.addView(createEditText(id + "." + listaPergunta.get(position).getTxtPergunta(), lines, editText));
```

Comment: Você tem que inserir seu código aqui, senão fica difícil te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Para o **setInputType** coloque o valor referente ao tipo de campo. Exemplo campo senha, campo numérico, campo texto e etc.

```
EditText edit = new EditTex(context);   
edit.setEnabled(true);
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
edit.setFocusable(true);
```